# Umbraco Razor orderby numeric property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have a property in an Umbraco document type of `numeric` called position (see below).

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
  var results = CurrentPage.Children(); 
}

@foreach(var result in results.OrderBy("position"))
{
  @result.position
}
```

I am expecting to see `1, 2, 3, 4 ... 11, 12...`

However, I am actually seeing `1, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4...`

The position property is set as numeric in Umbraco, but I cannot seem to alter the order to be integer-based rather than string-based.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually working as expected. Although your field is a numeric field, any values accessed via a dynamic property like `CurrentPage` will be treated as a string value (if it exists).

You can call:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    var results = ((DynamicNodeList)this.CurrentPage.ChildrenAsList);

    foreach(var result in results.OrderBy(x => x.Position())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This converts the children into a strongly typed list object that you can then perform LINQ against.

*Update:*

You could also use this provided you are using a later version:

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    var results = this.Model.Content.Children;

    foreach(var result in results.OrderBy(x => x.Position())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I then get this error: `CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DynamicNodeList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Do I need another namespace?

Comment: Yes apologies, you'll need `@using umbraco.MacroEngines`

Comment: Thanks, but I now have an error that states this type cannot support the "where" clause: `CS1928: 'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Where'` - is this not possible for DynamicNodeList?

Comment: You'll need to add `@using System.Linq`. We'll get there!

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error: `CS1928: 'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentExtensions.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent>, System.Func<Umbraco.Core.Models.IPublishedContent,bool>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: This error says that you are using a Where() extension method but this isn't in your example. I suspect that your example is working fine now and this error is being thrown by something else.

Answer (score -2):

This is because to numbers are being ordered by the first #, hence the `1, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4...`
You can try adding a padding to the left of the position, if your not to worried about loosing the dynamic properties, you can try the following;

```
@{
    var results = Model.Content.Children();  

    foreach(var result in results.OrderBy(x => x.position.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0')))
    {
        @result.GetPropertyValue("position")
    } 
}
```

[Pad Left >>>](http://www.dotnetperls.com/padleft)

Comment: I don't think that even compiles.